# Facebook Audience Network - Get Ad Placement Id

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-audience-network

I'm implementing the Facebook Audience Network SDK across iOS and Android. I set certain flags by checking a dictionary for the existence of an Ad, by looking up the Ads placementId. On iOS you can access this via the delegate methods easily, as below:

```
- (void)adView:(FBAdView *)adView didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Adview placement id is: %@", adView.placementId);
}
```

However on Android, the Ad object (in the Ad's listener) doesn't seem to have a placementId property as it's encapsulated. So this is either the usual inconsistencies between third-party SDK's cross platform, or i'm missing something?

Is it possible to retrieve the Ads placement id directly from the Ad object on Android, as you can do on iOS?

(Note: Facebook's docs don't seem to mention it)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [`AdView`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/current/class/AdView/) object in the Android implementation? it contains the `placementId` as well.